Salesforce Lightning Web Component: getting component error C.default.parse is not a function, when invoking PapaParse
I am importing PapaParse as a Static Resource into my Salesforce Lightning Web Component, and it should be loading it successfully. When I execute the file upload handler, I am getting a component error  [C.default.parse is not a function]. Is there something that I am missing?
Here is my JS controller code snippet.
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import PARSER from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/PapaParse';

////////

librariesLoaded = false;
renderedCallback() {
        if (this.librariesLoaded) return;
        
        Promise.all([loadScript(this, PARSER)])
        .then(() => {
            this.librariesLoaded = true;
            console.log(`## load script success`); // prints out successfully
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("## failure loading static resource PapaParse");
        });
    }

handleInputChange(event){
        if(event.target.files.length > 0){
            console.log(`## papaparse handler`);
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            this.loading = true;
            PARSER.parse(file, {
                quoteChar: '"',
                header: 'true',
                complete: (results) => {
                    this._rows = results.data;
                    console.log(`## papaparse rows: ${JSON.stringify(this._rows)}`);
                    this.loading = false;
                },
                error: (error) => {
                    console.error('## error' + error);
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            })
        }

Component Error
The checkbox for Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components and Aura components was unchecked by default, so I checked it. Same result.
